# Remove ripple effect from AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, material-design

I have `AutoCompleteTextView` inside `TextInputLayout`. How do I remove the ripple effect from AutoCompleteTextView when selecting item from drop down.

I am talking about the ripple on the widget and not the ripple inside the dropdown menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have samothing like this `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,language);`
change `android.R.layout.select_dialog_item` to your costume xml

Comment: I am talking about the ripple on the widget and not the ripple inside the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to this

1. Use **colorControlHighlight** attribute in a theme and apply it to TextInputLayout using style.
2. Set `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` in MaterialAutoCompleteTextView. Basically we need to set any inputType which is editable, then ripple would not be there.